# Running a list of apis via Python's request module

Tags: api, python, jupyter

I am running the following Python code with `python requests` in my Jupiter notebook to get cancer oncology id's from EBI-EMBL.

```
import requests
cancer_all = requests.get('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0000376/children')
obi = cancer_all.json()
```

The above code is for one link. However I want to get results for 30 such links together.

Other examples of links:

```
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0000621/children
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0000637/children
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0000653/children
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0002402/children
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0002516/children
https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0002813/children
```

**Questions**

1. Is there any way I can run all these api in one go?
2. Could I fetch the results (in json format) of these links in a single download. Thus there would be one json file for all the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json #??

apiString = "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0000621/children\nhttps://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0000637/children\nhttps://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0000653/children\nhttps://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0002402/children\nhttps://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0002516/children\nhttps://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0002813/children"

def requestIt():
    cancer_all = requests.get('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies/efo/terms/http%253A%252F%252Fpurl.obolibrary.org%252Fobo%252FMONDO_0000376/children')
    return cancer_all.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
callList = split('\n')
obi = [requestIt(x) for x in callList]

# e.g. 
print (obi[0]

# an alternative approach to list comprehension 
# computationally faster but will not make much difference here
obi = list(map(requestIt, callList)
```

**Note** If you want to parallelise it, which might be what you meant by 'all at once', you instantiate `Pool()` from `multiprocessor` via `map` and use the same comprehension but this time the function `requestIt` will spread this over your available CPUs. Thats a little bit more complicated - namely getting the result back.

If the apis are in a file they will load into a list nicely:

```
with open ('apis.txt', 'r') as fin:
    callList = fin.readlines()
```

**However** you want to combine the json into a single json ... you `import json` then use `json.loads` to convert the json into a dictionary, combine the dictionaries and then use `json.dumps` to convert it back to json. The code for that is a separate question altogether and the comprehension might be better expressed as a dictionary comprehension (not sure).